# how to display user details with ionic ngResource

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I am using ngResource to make login page by phone number and i want to show user details after successful login but i can't make ng-repeat with response

My Controller

```
.factory('Post', function($resource) {
  return $resource('http://localhost/scripts/order_system/new_api/api/view_order',{phone: "@phone"});
})
.controller('ViewCtrl', function($scope, Post, Authorization, $state) {
  $scope.postData = Authorization;

  $scope.posts = Post.query(function(data){
    $scope.post = data[0];
  })


  $scope.postData = {};
  $scope.newPost = function() {
    var post = new Post($scope.postData);
    post.$save();
    $state.go('tab.account');
  }
$scope.postData = Authorization;

})
```

After successfully login response

```
[
    {
        "user_id": "1847",
        "user_name": "USERNAME",
        "user_phone": "010236544525"
    }
]
```

> I want to show in account view user_name and user_phone

Answer (score 0):

Since your response is an array, so to get the first post(i.e first object), you need to do:

```
$scope.posts = Post.query().then(function(data){
    $scope.post = data[0];
});
```

And in your view, you can access `user_name` and `user_phone` like this:

```
{{post.user_name}}

{{post.user_phone}}
```

Comment: Where i add this code in controller $scope.post = $scope.posts[0]

Comment: I have updated my answer to show how to get the post.

Comment: Thank you for replay but code not working for me, i update my controller code

Comment: Can you create a fiddle. I can help you better.